# add uiimageview and uilabel on didSelectRowAtIndexPath +uiTableview

Tags: iphone, uitableview

i want to at add the uiimageview and uilabel into the selected row.
Now when i select the row in table then

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Deselect cell
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

> tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:TRUE]; 

        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            imageView1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"AboutImage.png"]];
            imageView1.center = CGPointMake(310, 48);
            [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView1];
            [imageView1 release];

            imageView2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"AboutImage.png"]];
            imageView2.center = CGPointMake(310, 48);
            [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView2];
            [imageView2 release];
```

But then also after doing this the imageview is not appeared..
Please anyone help me..How to add the uiimageview and label into cell.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't set frame for your imageview, I think that's the problem. So try this

Set it as

```
    imageView1.frame = CGRectMake();
```

set the frame according to your requirement....

Answer (score 2):

You need to ad this code:-

```
cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexpath];
```

Answer (score 1):

You should get the selected cell using

```
[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

then you can add the views on it